# Uploading files to google colab

Tags: r, upload, google-colaboratory

How do you upload a .Rdata file into google colab?

I have a data file of about 1.8GB and can't seem to get it into colab. I have uploaded it into google drive. I want to use R only not python. However when I try using get_drive I get an error message saying

> Error: Can't get google credentials.

Answer (score 0):

```
system("gdown --id 12uRyLU-aAdInBtkVubhI4l3PmbYIo5aE")
data = read.csv("data.csv")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.